# WordPress: echo custom user meta data field

Tags: php, wordpress

I put custom user meta field in WordPress it is working fine. With this code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ld_modify_contact_methods' ) ) :

    function ld_modify_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
        $contactmethods['dealername'] = __( 'Dealer Name' );
        return $contactmethods;
    }
add_filter('user_contactmethods','ld_modify_contact_methods', 10, 1);
```

Now i'm trying to echo it's value on the front-end with this code:

```
$dealername = get_the_author_meta( 'dealername', $post->post_author ); 
 echo $dealername;
```

Also with this code:

```
echo get_the_author_meta( 'dealername');
```

Both are not working.
Can anyone tell what i'm doing mistake here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, but you can also try with `get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'dealername', true )` And if that doesn't work either, then perhaps the user (`$post->post_author`) does not currently have a Dealer Name. You may also need to `global $post;` somewhere.

Comment: Did't work :( thanks.

Comment: But i'm also using this to display name echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);  it's working fine.

Comment: In that case, then do a `var_dump( $post->post_author );` and see if it prints the correct ID. If yes, check the *wp-admin* dashboard and see if the user has the Dealer Name field set to a valid value. And did you add `global $post;` before displaying the Dealer Name meta data? If *yes*, then add `wp_reset_postdata();` before the `global $post;` line.